# eliminate overlapping quarters from grouped user usage

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of user activity. I have the HWA, the date of activity, and a groupID. I get the quarters a user had activity based on a date range i.e.:

Date Range: 2011-08-01 - 2012-07-31

```
Q1 - Aug-Oct
Q2 - Nov-Jan
Q3 - Feb-Apr
Q4 - May-Jul
```

Some HWAs are replacements of others. In these cases they have the same groupID to show that they are linked. In these cases, I need to cancel out overlapping quarters. To clarify, if two HWAs have usage in quarter 2 and they have the same groupID, then I need to only count quarter 2 for one of them (which does not matter). Below is the query I am now using with the output I get:

```
SELECT act.HWA, count(act.HWA), m.Status, m.GroupID
    FROM (
        SELECT 
          a.HWA, a.Date,
          CASE 
            WHEN MONTH(a.Date) BETWEEN 8 AND 10 THEN 'Q1'
            WHEN (MONTH(a.Date) BETWEEN 11 AND 12 OR MONTH(a.Date) = 1) THEN 'Q2'
            WHEN MONTH(a.Date) BETWEEN 2 AND 4 THEN 'Q3'
            WHEN MONTH(a.Date) BETWEEN 5 AND 7 THEN 'Q4'
          END AS quarter,
          CASE
            WHEN MONTH(a.Date) <= 7 THEN YEAR(a.Date) - 1 
            ELSE EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from a.Date)
          END AS quarteryear,
          COUNT(*) AS num_activites
        FROM activity a
        WHERE a.InstitutionNumber = '000000000075'  
          AND (a.HWA = '001372EADBC4' 
            OR a.HWA = '180373E241DB' 
            OR a.HWA = '180373E23DE7')
          AND (a.Date between '2011-08-01' and '2012-07-31')
        GROUP BY
          quarter,
          a.HWA
    ) act, machine m
    where act.HWA = m.HWA
    group by act.HWA
```

Which returns this:

```
HWA             quarters      status      groupid

001372EADBC4        3        deleted        59970
180373E23DE7        2         online        59970
180373E241DB        1        deleted        59970
```

Expected results would be:

HWA             quarters      status      groupid

```
001372EADBC4        2        deleted        59970
180373E23DE7        2         online        59970
180373E241DB        0        deleted        59970
```

Here is a list of quarters for each HWA that I produce by changing the above query a little. You can see that all three HWAs have share quarter 3 and I want only one of them to have quarter 3:

```
001372EADBC4    1   deleted 59970
001372EADBC4    2   deleted 59970
001372EADBC4    3   deleted 59970
180373E23DE7    3   online  59970
180373E241DB    3   deleted 59970
180373E23DE7    4   online  59970
```

Comment: whats the difrences between your current result and the wanted result, can't see any dublicate values in your current result

Comment: It would be good to add some sample table data (with the corresponding expected results) for us to work with.

Comment: You could use math to count the quarter insted of a big case, `CONCAT('Q', 1 + (FLOOR((MONTH(a.Date) + 4)/3) % 4)` AS quarter, where '+4' is the number of months before newyear that the first quarter starts

Comment: I added to my original post to show what I want to get and what data I am looking at

Comment: The initial problem was that I had the same groupID with multiple of the same quarters. I needed to have only one instance of a quarter for all HWAs that have the same group ID. The solution gives me exactly that. Before the fix as I show above, I had 6 total quarters for groupid 59970. With the fix there are only 4 as should be because the duplicates of quarter 3 were eliminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out by just changing around groupings for the most part:

```
SELECT act.HWA, count(act.HWA), m.Status, m.GroupID
  FROM (
   SELECT 
      a.HWA, a.Date,
      CASE
        WHEN MONTH(a.Date) BETWEEN 8 AND 10 THEN '1'
        WHEN (MONTH(a.Date) BETWEEN 11 AND 12 OR MONTH(a.Date) = 1) THEN '2'
        WHEN MONTH(a.Date) BETWEEN 2 AND 4 THEN '3'
        WHEN MONTH(a.Date) BETWEEN 5 AND 7 THEN '4'
       END AS quarter,
       CASE
          WHEN MONTH(a.Date) <= 7 THEN YEAR(a.Date) - 1 
          ELSE EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from a.Date)
        END AS quarteryear,
        COUNT(*) AS num_activites
      FROM activity a, machine m
      WHERE
        a.InstitutionNumber = '000000000075'
        AND m.InstitutionID = 14
        AND (a.HWA = '001372EADBC4' 
            OR a.HWA = '180373E241DB' 
            OR a.HWA = '180373E23DE7')
        AND a.HWA = m.HWA
        AND (a.Date between '2011-08-01' and '2012-07-31')
        AND a.EngineRequests > 0
        AND a.FilesAnalyzed > 0
      GROUP BY
        quarter,
        m.GroupID
  ) act, machine m
WHERE act.HWA = m.HWA
AND m.InstitutionID = 14
GROUP BY act.HWA
```

I added in the following in the SELECT act:

AND m.InstitutionID = 14
 Group By m.GroupID

and I removed the following from the SELECT act:

Group By a.HWA